# How to group and Throttle Object by ID Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have incoming objects of the same type, but if An Object property `IsThrottlable` is set to false regardless of the ID I DON'T want to throttle it but if `IsThrottlable` is set to true I would like to throttle the object every 3 seconds by ID. So if an object with the same ID comes in 50 times with 3 seconds I would like to send the HTTPSend for the last Object.

```
namespace BoatThrottle
{
    class MData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public bool IsThrottlable { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();

            while (true)
            {
                var data = GenerateRandomObj(rand);
                SendData(data);
                Task.Delay(rand.Next(100, 2000));
            }
        }

        static MData GenerateRandomObj(Random rand)
        {
            return new MData() { ID = rand.Next(1, 20), Description = "Notification....", IsThrottlable = (rand.Next(2) == 1) };
        }

        static void SendData(MData mData)
        {
            if (mData.IsThrottlable)
            {
                _doValues.OnNext(mData);
                var dd = ThrottledById(DoValues);

                var observable =
                   dd
                    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000.0))
                    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool.DisableOptimizations());

                _subscription =
                    observable
                    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool.DisableOptimizations())
                        .Subscribe(y =>
                        {
                            HTTPSend(y);
                        });

            }
            else
            {
                // MData object coming in IsThrottlable set to false always send this data NO throttling
                HTTPSend(mData);
            }

        }
        private static IDisposable? _subscription = null;

        public static IObservable<MData> ThrottledById(IObservable<MData> observable)
        {
            return observable.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
                .SelectMany(x =>
                    x.GroupBy(y => y.ID)
                    .Select(y => y.Last()));
        }

        private static readonly Subject<MData> _doValues = new Subject<MData>();

        public static IObservable<MData> DoValues { get { return _doValues; } }

        static void HTTPSend(MData mData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("===============HTTP===>>  " + mData.ID + "  " + mData.Description + " " + mData.IsThrottlable);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

e.g **ALL received within 3 seconds**

- MData ID = 1, IsThrottlable = False, Description = "Notify"
- MData ID = 2, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify1"
- MData ID = 2, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify2"
- MData ID = 9, IsThrottlable = False, Description = "Notify2"
- MData ID = 2, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify3"
- MData ID = 2, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify4"
- MData ID = 3, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify"
- MData ID = 4, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify"
- MData ID = 5, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify1"
- MData ID = 5, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify2"
- MData ID = 8, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify1"
- MData ID = 8, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify2"
- MData ID = 8, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify3"
- MData ID = 8, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify4"
- MData ID = 8, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify5"
- MData ID = 8, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify6"

Expected at the  **First 3 seconds**:

- MData ID = 1, IsThrottlable = False, Description = "Notify"
- MData ID = 9, IsThrottlable = False, Description = "Notify2"
- MData ID = 2, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify4"
- MData ID = 3, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify"
- MData ID = 4, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify"
- MData ID = 5, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify2"
- MData ID = 8, IsThrottlable = True, Description = "Notify6"

Comment: If your final implementation is an answer to your own question then post it as one. Don't put it in the question.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have removed it from the question thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to group the sequence by the `IsThrottlable` property. This way you'll get a nested sequence that contains two subsequences, one containing the throttleable elements and one containing the non-throttleable elements. You can then transform each of the two subsequences accordingly, and finally use the `SelectMany` operator to flatten the nested sequence back to a flat sequence that contains the elements emitted by the two transformed subsequences.

The subsequence that contains the non-throttleable elements needs no transformation, so you can return it as is.

The subsequence that contains the throttleable elements needs to be grouped further by the `ID` property, producing even thinner subsequences that contain only throttleable elements having the same id. These are the sequences that need to be throttled:

```
IObservable<MData> throttled = source
    .GroupBy(x => x.IsThrottlable)
    .SelectMany(g1 =>
    {
        if (!g1.Key) return g1; // Not throttleable, return it as is.
        return g1
            .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
            .SelectMany(g2 => g2.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
    });
```

At the end you'll get a flat sequence that contains both the throttleable and the non-throttleable items, with the throttleable items already throttled by id.

The `SelectMany` operator is essentially a combination of the `Select`+`Merge` operators.

Comment: Have you got example on usage in the context?

Comment: @Dev my intention was to show the basic idea. I'll let you have the pleasure of adapting it to the context. :-)

Comment: agreed :) I meant as in how to separate the `IsThrottlable` subscriptions

Comment: @Dev couldn't you just subscribe only to the resulting `throttled` sequence? This way you'll get both throttleable and non-throttleable items, but the throttleable items will be already throttled. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Ahh right it make sense to me now, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are right this is not what I want or its possible am not using it correctly. But its meant to group by `IsThrottlable` Then Group BY ID and Throttle each group. So throttle only if `IsThrottlable` is true and then Group by ID if the Object ID is the same Throttle. So e.g imagine the single objects coming in are User objects and if the `IsThrottlable` = true if the request is coming from the same user ID HTTPsend the Last object of each unique user.

Comment: I have edited the Question with  an Example of 1 instance of a 3 second cycle, is this what the answer is intended to do? spent  a few hours tweaking it but not getting the desired result

Comment: @Dev now I think I got it. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have added my final implementation(Edited my question at the bottom) because It is only Httpsending to only if `IsThrottlable` =False. `IsThrottlable`  is not printing at all.

Comment: @Dev I've posted an online demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WCpWAz). The output matches what is expected in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244565/discussion-between-dev-and-theodor-zoulias).

Answer (score 1):

I decided to take your final implementation, as posted in your question, but it should be as an answer, and clean up the query for you in a way that is the most idiomatic Rx kind of way.

Here's my version of your code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Debug.Print("========================");

    _subscription =
        Observable
            .Generate(0, x => true, x => x + 1,
                x => new MData() { ID = Random.Shared.Next(1, 3), Description = "Notification....", IsThrottlable = Random.Shared.Next(2) == 1 },
                x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Random.Shared.Next(100, 2000)))
            .GroupBy(m => m.IsThrottlable)
            .SelectMany(g =>
                g.Key
                ? g.GroupBy(x => x.ID).SelectMany(g2 => g2.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0)))
                : g)
            .SelectMany(m => Observable.Start(() => HTTPSend(m)))
            .Subscribe();
}
```

The final `.SelectMany(m => Observable.Start(() => HTTPSend(m)))` might need to be written as `.Select(m => Observable.Start(() => HTTPSend(m))).Merge(1)`.

Comment: +1. You might need to wrap the `Observable.Start` in a `Observable.Defer`, especially if you intend to merge the subsequences lazily with Merge(1). Otherwise the `HTTPSend` might be invoked before the subsequence is subscribed.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Thank you. But why might `HTTPSend` be invoked before the subscription?

Comment: Check out [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LD8MDQ) demo. The `sequence` is not subscribed. Nevertheless the action is invoked.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Well, that's interesting. A quick look at the source shows it to be true too. It ends up caching the result for all future callers.

Comment: The `Observable.Start` is the synchronous version of the `Observable.StartAsync`. As far as I can see there is no synchronous version of the `Observable.FromAsync`. Maybe they couldn't settle in a suitable name for that method.

Comment: This Instance `Observable
          .Generate(0, x => true, x => x + 1,
              x => new MData() { ID = 5, Description = "Notification....", IsThrottlable = true },
              x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(rand.Next(100, 2000)))`  Does not print at all.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - We kind of need `public static class ObservableEx { public static IObservable<T> From<T>(this Func<T> factory) => Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.Run(factory)); }`

Comment: @Dev - It works for me without change from the code you posted in the comment. Mind you there's nothing in there that "prints", but if you subscribe it produces values.

Comment: @Enigmativity apologies, it works(as in it generates the objects), but What I meant was I replaced the Random elements of the Observable.Generate to only have a `IsThrottlable` = true and ID= 5 always to ensure the HTTPSend works with only 1 type/group, so it should print the last value every interval.

Comment: Enigmativity, yes, this should also do the job. The implementation I had in mind is: `From<T>(this Func<T> action) => Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(action));`